# Может ли между частями сложного предложения, связанными сочинительной связью, стоять часть, связанная с одной из тех частей бессоюзной связью?

Tags: синтаксис

Мальчики спиной ко мне – я видел их тоненькие шеи, а девочка – лицом. 
Первая часть связана с третьей с помощью сочинительного союза "а". Первая и вторая части связаны бессоюзной связью. Разве может быть так построено сложносочинённое предложение, когда между ними не придаточное, относящееся к одной из частей, а часть без союза? Мне кажется, что часть " я видел их тонкие шеи" является вводным предложением.

Answer (score 1):

В вашем примере часть "я видел их тоненькие шеи" является не вводным предложением, а вставной конструкцией в сложном предложении. Здесь нет бессоюзной связи.

Вставные конструкции (слова, сочетания слов, предложения) выделяются скобками или тире. Они содержат дополнительные сведения, замечания, уточнения, пояснения, поправки к сказанному; разъясняют, толкуют основную часть высказывания:

Нас хорошо кормили, но воды — не питьевой, а для умывания — было мало (Кав.); Иногда дни сверкали лучше летних — белизна замороженного снега в упор сопротивлялась солнечному огню — и чистый воздух остро мерцал от колкого холода и тягучего тепла (Плат.); За темным каналом — это и была Пряжка — подымались стапели судостроительных заводов (Пауст.).